# I want something like that => $(this).('#id').css('display','inline');

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to resolve this for quite some time now. 
Simply here is what im trying to do.

When you click on the option absent, a pop up box should come out. 
What happens with me is that the same pop up box shows however i want the pop up box that is relevant to the table name.

Here is my code below:

```
    while($row_students = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_students))
    {
    $student_name = $row_students['first_name'] .' '. $row_students['middle_name']  .' '. $row_students['last_name'];
    $student_id = $row_students['id'];
    echo 
    "<tr> 
    <td>{$student_id}</td>
    <td>{$student_name}</td>
    <td>{$row_students['batch_id']}</td>
    <td>
    <select class='form-control' name='reason{$student_id}' id='selection' >
    <option value='NA' style='display:none';>Type of Absence</option>
    <option value='absent'>Absent</option>
    <option value='late'>Late</option>
    <option value='sick'>Sick</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>

    <select class='form-control' name='popupreason{$student_id}' 
    id='popup-text' style='display:none;'>

    <option value='NA' style='display:none';>Please Select Reason</option>
    <option value='death'>حالة وفاه</option>
    <option value='tardy'>لم يتم اللحاق بحافلة المدرسة </option>
    <option value='force'>مانع خارج عن الإرادة </option>
    <option value='accident'>حادث في الطريق  </option>
    <option value='travel'>السفر </option>
    <option value='expelled'>رفد مؤقت  </option>
    <option value='financial'>مانع مادي</option>
    <option value='unknown'>غير معروف</option>                    
    </select>     
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>";   
    } 
    }
    ?>
And for Jquery:

    <script>


  $("select[id='selection']").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() === 'absent'){
         $('#popup-text').css('display','inline');
        }
      });



 /*I BELIEVE THE ISSUE IS HERE IN THE ABOVE AS I NEED TO USE SOMETHING LIKE 


$(this).('#popup-text').css('display','inline');
  BUT I COULDN'T GET THE SYNTAX CORRECT  */

  $('#popup-text').change(function(){
    $("#popup-text").hide();
  })

   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this'll work:

```
$("select[id='selection']").change(function() {
  var studentId = $(this).attr('name').match(/^reason(\d+)$/i)[1];

  $('#popup-text[name=popupreason' + studentId + ']')
    .css('display','inline')
    .focus()
  ;
});
```

Or just:

```
$("select[id='selection']").change(function(){
  $("#popup-text").hide(); // hide others

  if ($(this).val() === 'absent'){
      $('[name=popup' + $(this).attr('name') + ']')
        .css('display','inline')
      ;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have same ID in every iteration, and since ID must be unique per page - it invalid. Use classes for that.

Than you can do

```
$(".selection").change(function(){
   if ($(this).val() === 'absent'){
       $(this)
          .closest('tr') // find first tr in parents for current element
          .next() // select next tr element
          .find('.popup-text') // find select with relevant class in that tr
          .css('display','inline') // change it's display
       ;
   }
});
```